# Cannot Unhide Android System Bar after Hiding

Tags: java, android, system, root

I have a rooted Nexus 10 on 4.3, and hiding the system bar with the following code works fine:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity "+ ProcID +" s16 com.android.systemui"}); //WAS 79
proc.waitFor();
```

But when I try to unhide it with the following code, it never unhides:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"am","startservice","-n","com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"});
proc.waitFor();
```

If I issue the "am" command from adb shell, it works as advertised (system bar reappears).  There is a try/catch around the root calls and there is no exception. I get a completion code of "1" out of "am".

The hide and show are in two different activities within the same app, though I don't see why that would matter.

For those interested, this is for a kiosk app where the bar needs to go away while it is running, then reappear when the app is exited from a hidden menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I managed to get the System Bar to hide and appear in a 4.2 device using:

To Hide:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

Or use 79 instead of 42 for API less than 14. You may also need to include the SET_DEBUG_APP permission, in which case you need to have the application signed with the system key or installed in the /system/app/ directory.

To Show:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
```

Alternatively some people have used the -a (instead of -n) option, though this was causing an error on my device:

Error: Not found; no service started.

Comment: This code is working through adb not through the application.